# Display code coverage report using laravel route

Tags: laravel, jestjs, routes, report, code-coverage

I have created jest code coverage report using command `npx jest --coverage`. It creates `coverage` directory in the root as below:

```
laravel_project
- app
- config
- coverage
-- lcov-report
--- index.html
--- prettify.js
--- prettify.css
```

When I open the `index.html` on my local the report looks proper as below. (JS & CSS created by the command loads properly)

[image: code_coverage_expected]

I am trying to display the same code coverage report using a route as below.

```
Route::get('/reports/jest-coverage', function () {
    return File::get(base_path('coverage/lcov-report/index.html'));
});
```

but CSS and JS included in the `index.html` breaks as Laravel doesn't allow to load resourses outside the `public` directory.

[image: code_coverage_broken]

The JS & CSS files are included as below in the `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prettify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
<script src="prettify.js"></script>
```

How I can achieve this without modifying `coverage` directory?
Is there any way in Laravel to achieve this?

Comment: Browser sees only what is in public directory. If you serve some files from outside public directory it has to be prepared fully to be rendered (i.e. it should be rendered as inline stylesheet with JS code in that `index.html`) that is called with Laravel's `File::get` method. Maybe if you would set `coverage` as subdirectory of `public`?